# Unable to cast object to type MembershipUser

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am trying to override the GetUser function of the MembershipProvider to simply get a user so I can access their properties from my database.  I tried this:

```
Public Overloads Overrides Function GetUser(username As String, userIsOnline As Boolean) As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser
    Dim user = db.Tbl_Employees.Where(Function(u) u.Employee_EmailAddress = username)
    Return user
End Function
```

However, I get the error:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[MyBlog.Tbl_Employee]' to
>   type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'.

I understand it is returning the same type when I say, " As System.Web.Security.MembershipUser" so should I change that or should I try to cast it somehow?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're going about this entirely wrong.  You can't just cast things to random other things.  They have to actually BE the thing you are casting it to.

What you should be doing is simply returning the ProviderUserKey from your GetUser method and then using that to lookup whatever other data you want in your user table, outside of the membership system.

EDIT:

```
var userid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;  // cast to your type 

var user = db.Tbl_Employees.Where(x => x.UserId == userid);
```

Comment: I don't understand when you say, "`What you should be doing is simply returning the ProviderUserKey from your GetUser method and then using that to lookup whatever other data you want in your user table, outside of the membership system.`"  Can you show me what you mean I should do?

Comment: @user1477388 - that's pretty self explanatory.  Call GetUser. get the ProviderUserKey from the MembershipUser returned by the membership provider, lookup your user by the ProviderUserKey using normal database methods.

Comment: I don't seem to have any methods for ProvideUserKey.  Can you please post an example since it's so simple?

Comment: So this looks like it's for use in a controller.  I shouldn't do anything with my GetUser method in my CustomMembershipProvider?

Comment: @user1477388 - Why do you have a Custom membership provider?

Comment: Because I'm using a custom database (Employees).

Comment: @user1477388 - Regardless of whether you have a custom membership provider or not, you can't make it return anything other than MembershipUser.  So you have to return a MembershipUser and use the ProviderUserKey

Comment: Thanks, Mystere Man.  I am just wondering how your solution fits in with my GetUser() method?

Comment: @user1477388 - you don't need to use a custom membership provider to use your own Employees table.  You just add a foreign key to your Employees table that contains your ProviderUserKey, then you use the standard membership provider.

Comment: @user1477388 - Your GetUser method is wrong and will not work.  You can't cast an employee table to a MembershipUser, and you can't change the return type because you're inheriting the type.

Comment: I am already using it successfully as I have overridden the ValidateUser method which works properly.  I am asking to override the GetUser() property but I am not sure how.  Can you show me how to override the GetUser() method so that it returns a user (or MembershipUser)?

Comment: @user1477388 - You can't override GetUser in the way you want to.  Stop trying, because you can't.  You can only return a MembershipUser.  That's it.

Comment: That's fine.  Can you show me how to return a MembershipUser, via the GetUser() method, then?

Comment: @user1477388 - umm.. really?  That's like something you should have learned on your first day of programming.  You create a new MembershipUser, then you fill it with values and use the return keyword to return it.

Comment: Dude seriously, with the condescending tone!?  Are you kidding me?  Are you going to help or not?

Comment: @user1477388 - Dude, seriously, it's that simple.  Maybe you should watch this video, there's even a vb version.  http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-create-a-custom-membership-provider

Comment: The video doesn't go over GetUser, just CreateUser and ValidateUser...  Still at square one.  I see I have to do `Return New MembershipUser("", user.Employee_EmailAddress, user.Employee_ID, user.Employee_EmailAddress, "", "", True, False, "", "", "", "", "")` but I don't have fields for all of those in my db.

Comment: @user1477388 - then just supply nulls or default values.  Those fields are only used by you.

Comment: Instead of using GetUser, can't I just put some code in my View using Razor?  I am simply trying to get a user's first name and last name into my View Partial.  I have `@User.Identity.Name` but I can't seem to access my Employee entity from my view.  Is there some special import I need to add to be able to access it?

Comment: @user1477388 - I have no idea, you would need to provide a lot more information about the structure of your project.  You're asking me to help you with things I can't possibly know.

Comment: Okay, no problem.  Sorry for yelling at you earlier :)

Comment: @user1477388 - look, your problem is that you're using the Membership system in a way it wasn't intended to be used.  You should just use the default membership provider, then add a column to your Employee table for the ProviderUserKey.  Then you can do exactly what I said in my answer.  It's simple, and you're not fighting the system.  There is no reason with your simple needs that you can't just use the default provider.

Comment: Thanks, but I realized I don't even want the GetUser data, instead I just need to access my Employee table based on the UserName of the current user.

Answer (score 1):

GetUser is expecting a type of MembershipUser. You are returning something that does not derive from that object, so it complains.

You will have to either map the entity into a custom object that inherits from MembershipUser, or create a new one, passing in the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Can you show me an example of either method?  Can't I just change the return type from MembershipUser to "Employee" from my custom Employee model, or isn't this advised?

Comment: You can't change the return type because it must have the same signature as the base class.